# "FirewallD not running" error when trying to install a printer

Tags: 11.10, printing, firewall

When trying to add my printer in a fresh install of 11.10 I get this error message.  What does it mean, and what do I have to do?  It worked fine in 11.04 (with hplip).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/871985) and this is a workaround.:

> WORKAROUND: As an alternative to the printer configuration tool from
>   the new GNOME Shell control center, you can still use
>   `system-config-printer`. To open it, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type
>   `system-config-printer` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make sense of system-config-printer, but it turns out `CUPS` has a web-based UI which is automatically available via:

http://localhost:631/

Just open that up, then

`Administration`-->`Add Printer`

it auto-detected a network printer for me, no problem.