# How do I install my HP printer through network?

Tags: networking, printing, hplip

- When I plug the HP Deskjet2050j510 printer directly on my PC **through USB cable, it is perfect**.
  [image]
- But when trying **through network, it can not find it**.
  [image]
  [image]

**Note**
I'm using the HPLIP Toolbox to search the printer.
I also desactived the firewall.
My internet box is supposed to allow such functionality, it is a Livebox from Orange(France). [Here is the documentation](http://help.orange.co.uk/orangeuk/support/personal/223157/3), but for Windows, not Ubuntu
My network installation is the following one: 2 PCs connected to the Livebox and the printer connected by USB to the Livebox too.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try to find your printer through the normal printer dialog. You can find the dialog in the upper right 'gear' menu.

Click on `+ Add`, then go to Network printers and then select your printer.

[image: printer dialog]

Comment: I m not sure that we have the same "normal printer dialog". I m using Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-fallback. But anyway, trying through *System parameter| Printer* it tells me that *FirewallD* is not launched. So I going look for the meaning FirewallD ... here http://askubuntu.com/questions/71480/firewalld-not-running-error-when-trying-to-install-a-printer

Comment: perfect, using the workaround, alt+f2 `system-config-printer` I get the "normal printer dialog" like you and it works !!